# JavaFx Chart unrefresh in subscene with Oracle JDK10

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-9

I write a JavaFX Demo to add a bar chart in Subscene and change the bar chart series value in KeyFrame in Timeline.

In Oracle JDK8, the bar chart graphic refresh correct,But in Oracle JDK 10,the bar chart graphic do not refresh.

I tried Platform.requestNextPulse,but it donot useful.

Sorry for my poor English.

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;


public class HMIBrowserDemoTest extends Application {

    private Scene backScene=new Scene(new Group());

    SubScene subScene =null;

    private Group picGroup=null;


    public HMIBrowserDemoTest(){
        super();
    }

    private void initUI(Stage primaryStage) {

        Rectangle2D screenBounds=Screen.getPrimary().getBounds();
        primaryStage.setWidth(screenBounds.getWidth());
        primaryStage.setHeight(screenBounds.getHeight());
        primaryStage.centerOnScreen();

        primaryStage.setTitle("hmi.browser.title");

        primaryStage.setScene(backScene);

        Group rootGroup=(Group) backScene.getRoot();

        Group aa=new Group();
        aa.getChildren().add(createContent1());
        subScene =new SubScene(aa,800,700);
        subScene.setFill(Color.BEIGE);
        subScene.setManaged(false);

        rootGroup.getChildren().add(subScene);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        initUI(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();

        init1();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
        launch(args);
    }



    private void init1(){
        Timeline tl = new Timeline();
        tl.getKeyFrames().add(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(150),
                        new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                            @Override
                            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                                XYChart.Series series= (XYChart.Series) chart.getData().get(0);
                                int value= (int) (Math.random() * 5000);
                                XYChart.Data<String, Number> data= (XYChart.Data<String, Number>) series.getData().get(0);
                                System.out.println(value+"-----------");
                                data.setYValue(value);
                                subScene.toFront();
                            }
                        }
                ));
        tl.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        tl.setAutoReverse(true);
        tl.play();
    }

    private BarChart chart;
    private CategoryAxis xAxis;
    private NumberAxis yAxis;
    public Parent createContent1() {
        String[] years = {"2007", "2008", "2009"};
        xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        xAxis.setCategories(FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList(years));
        yAxis = new NumberAxis("Units Sold", 0.0d, 3000.0d, 1000.0d);
        ObservableList<BarChart.Series> barChartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new BarChart.Series("Apples", FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        new BarChart.Data(years[0], 567d),
                        new BarChart.Data(years[1], 1292d),
                        new BarChart.Data(years[2], 1292d)
                )),
                new BarChart.Series("Lemons", FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        new BarChart.Data(years[0], 956),
                        new BarChart.Data(years[1], 1665),
                        new BarChart.Data(years[2], 2559)
                )),
                new BarChart.Series("Oranges", FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        new BarChart.Data(years[0], 1154),
                        new BarChart.Data(years[1], 1927),
                        new BarChart.Data(years[2], 2774)
                ))
        );
        chart = new BarChart(xAxis, yAxis, barChartData, 25.0d);
        chart.setLayoutX(0);
        chart.setLayoutY(0);
        chart.setPrefSize(300,300);
        return chart;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can reproduce the same issue with JDK9 as well. This definitely looks like a bug in JavaFX. Can you log an issue for the same either in [JDK bug system](https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/) or on [JavaFX github mirror](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues) so that the JavaFX dev team can have a look at it?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha I send a report to javafx github